# True value being duplicated into incorrect user object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am having a very strange issue that hopefully someone can help me with. Here's what is happening:

A function called processServices is being used to take a large object called "flight" as well as GET values from a form on a previous page to add selected airline services to the appropriate user's 'profile' inside the object. It also then totals the price of the services for that particular user and adds it to the object.

These services are dynamic but that's not really relevant here apart from I can't expect any service code in my function and have to rely on the get data.

The PROBLEM is that if I have two users and the second one signs up for a service, the first user gets that service as well, even though that user's service total stays at zero.

Example of Flight object before running function:

```
[Flight] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Adults] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [FirstName] => Test
                                    [MiddleName] => 
                                    [LastName] => Account
                                    [Services] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [BLND] => 0
                                            [EMSA] => 0
                                            [PETH] => 0
                                            [SVAN] => 0
                                            [WCHR] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [FirstName] => The
                                    [MiddleName] => 
                                    [LastName] => Dude
                                    [Services] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [BLND] => 0
                                            [EMSA] => 0
                                            [PETH] => 0
                                            [SVAN] => 0
                                            [WCHR] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [AdultNum] => 2
                    [Services] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [LogicalFlightID] => 4569
                                    [ServiceID] => 0
                                    [DepartureDate] => 2017-04-03T00:00:00
                                    [OperatingCarrier] => 
                                    [MarketingCarrier] => 
                                    [CodeType] => BLND
                                    [Description] => Can Choose Own Seat
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [Amount] => 0.0
                                    [AmountActive] => 1
                                    [AmountType] => 
                                    [CategoryID] => 1
                                    [SSRCode] => BLND
                                    [Display] => 1
                                    [MaxCountServiceLevel] => 8
                                    [Refundable] => 
                                    [PNLActive] => 1
                                    [CutoffHours] => -1
                                    [Commissionable] => 
                                    [DisplayOrder] => 0
                                    [RevenueCategoryID] => 7
                                    [IATAStandardCodeType] => 
                                    [ServiceActive] => 1
                                    [MaxCountFlightLevel] => 0
                                    [QuantityAvailable] => 8
                                    [StartSalesDays] => -1
                                    [ApplicableTaxes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BoardingPassSsrOrder] => 999
                                    [Name] => Blind Passenger
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [LogicalFlightID] => 4569
                                    [ServiceID] => 0
                                    [DepartureDate] => 2017-04-03T00:00:00
                                    [OperatingCarrier] => 
                                    [MarketingCarrier] => 
                                    [CodeType] => EMSA
                                    [Description] => 
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [Amount] => 0.0
                                    [AmountActive] => 1
                                    [AmountType] => Flat Fee
                                    [CategoryID] => 221
                                    [SSRCode] => EMSA
                                    [Display] => 1
                                    [MaxCountServiceLevel] => 1
                                    [Refundable] => 1
                                    [PNLActive] => 1
                                    [CutoffHours] => 0
                                    [Commissionable] => 
                                    [DisplayOrder] => 0
                                    [RevenueCategoryID] => 7
                                    [IATAStandardCodeType] => 
                                    [ServiceActive] => 1
                                    [MaxCountFlightLevel] => 1
                                    [QuantityAvailable] => 1
                                    [StartSalesDays] => -1
                                    [ApplicableTaxes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BoardingPassSsrOrder] => 999
                                    [Name] => Emotional Support Animal
                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [LogicalFlightID] => 4569
                                    [ServiceID] => 0
                                    [DepartureDate] => 2017-04-03T00:00:00
                                    [OperatingCarrier] => 
                                    [MarketingCarrier] => 
                                    [CodeType] => PETH
                                    [Description] => PET IN HOLD
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [Amount] => 25
                                    [AmountActive] => 1
                                    [AmountType] => Flat Fee
                                    [CategoryID] => 221
                                    [SSRCode] => PETH
                                    [Display] => 1
                                    [MaxCountServiceLevel] => 1
                                    [Refundable] => 1
                                    [PNLActive] => 
                                    [CutoffHours] => 0
                                    [Commissionable] => 
                                    [DisplayOrder] => 0
                                    [RevenueCategoryID] => 7
                                    [IATAStandardCodeType] => 
                                    [ServiceActive] => 1
                                    [MaxCountFlightLevel] => 0
                                    [QuantityAvailable] => 0
                                    [StartSalesDays] => -1
                                    [ApplicableTaxes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BoardingPassSsrOrder] => 999
                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [LogicalFlightID] => 4569
                                    [ServiceID] => 0
                                    [DepartureDate] => 2017-04-03T00:00:00
                                    [OperatingCarrier] => 
                                    [MarketingCarrier] => 
                                    [CodeType] => SVAN
                                    [Description] => SERVICE ANIMAL
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [Amount] => 0.0
                                    [AmountActive] => 1
                                    [AmountType] => Flat Fee
                                    [CategoryID] => 221
                                    [SSRCode] => SVAN
                                    [Display] => 1
                                    [MaxCountServiceLevel] => 1
                                    [Refundable] => 1
                                    [PNLActive] => 1
                                    [CutoffHours] => 0
                                    [Commissionable] => 
                                    [DisplayOrder] => 0
                                    [RevenueCategoryID] => 7
                                    [IATAStandardCodeType] => 
                                    [ServiceActive] => 1
                                    [MaxCountFlightLevel] => 0
                                    [QuantityAvailable] => 0
                                    [StartSalesDays] => -1
                                    [ApplicableTaxes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BoardingPassSsrOrder] => 999
                                )

                            [4] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [LogicalFlightID] => 4569
                                    [ServiceID] => 0
                                    [DepartureDate] => 2017-04-03T00:00:00
                                    [OperatingCarrier] => 
                                    [MarketingCarrier] => 
                                    [CodeType] => WCHR
                                    [Description] => 
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [Amount] => 0.0
                                    [AmountActive] => 1
                                    [AmountType] => 
                                    [CategoryID] => 1
                                    [SSRCode] => WCHR
                                    [Display] => 1
                                    [MaxCountServiceLevel] => 8
                                    [Refundable] => 
                                    [PNLActive] => 1
                                    [CutoffHours] => -1
                                    [Commissionable] => 
                                    [DisplayOrder] => 0
                                    [RevenueCategoryID] => 7
                                    [IATAStandardCodeType] => 
                                    [ServiceActive] => 1
                                    [MaxCountFlightLevel] => 0
                                    [QuantityAvailable] => 8
                                    [StartSalesDays] => -1
                                    [ApplicableTaxes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BoardingPassSsrOrder] => 999
                                    [Name] => Wheelchair (can Climb Stairs And Walk To Chair)
                                )

                        )

                )
```

Below is the function. Note that the get data is structured as follows:
service-CODE-#, where CODE is the unique code for a service and # is the user id (starting with 0 and going up to 8). So, someone who is user 1 who wanted a pet in hold would have a get name like service-PETH-0

Function:

```
function processServices($flight, $get) {
    $totalCost = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<$flight->AdultNum; $i++) {
        $totalCost = 0;
        foreach($flight->Services as $s) {
            $code = $s->SSRCode;
            if ($get['service-'.$code.'-'.$i] == 'yes') {
                $flight->Adults[$i]->Services->$code = true;
                $totalCost += $s->Amount;
            } else {
                $flight->Adults[$i]->Services->$code = false;
            }
        }
        $flight->Adults[$i]->ServicesTotal = $totalCost;
        $totalCost = 0;
    }

    return $flight;
}
```

In this example the following is in the $_GET variable:

```
service-BLND-0=no&service-EMSA-0=no&service-PETH-0=no&service-SVAN-0=no&service-WCHR-0=no&service-BLND-1=no&service-EMSA-1=no&service-PETH-1=yes&service-SVAN-1=no&service-WCHR-1=no&step=4
```

But for some reason, after processing with that function, this is the new object (PETH is marked for BOTH users, even though it's only totaled for one):

```
[Flight] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Adults] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [FirstName] => Test
                                    [MiddleName] => 
                                    [LastName] => Account
                                    [Services] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [BLND] => 0
                                            [EMSA] => 0
                                            [PETH] => 1
                                            [SVAN] => 0
                                            [WCHR] => 0
                                        )
                                    [ServicesTotal] => 0
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [FirstName] => The
                                    [MiddleName] => 
                                    [LastName] => Dude
                                    [Services] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [BLND] => 0
                                            [EMSA] => 0
                                            [PETH] => 1
                                            [SVAN] => 0
                                            [WCHR] => 0
                                        )
                                    [ServicesTotal] => 25
                                )

                        )

                    [AdultNum] => 2
                    [Services] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [LogicalFlightID] => 4569
                                    [ServiceID] => 0
                                    [DepartureDate] => 2017-04-03T00:00:00
                                    [OperatingCarrier] => 
                                    [MarketingCarrier] => 
                                    [CodeType] => BLND
                                    [Description] => Can Choose Own Seat
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [Amount] => 0.0
                                    [AmountActive] => 1
                                    [AmountType] => 
                                    [CategoryID] => 1
                                    [SSRCode] => BLND
                                    [Display] => 1
                                    [MaxCountServiceLevel] => 8
                                    [Refundable] => 
                                    [PNLActive] => 1
                                    [CutoffHours] => -1
                                    [Commissionable] => 
                                    [DisplayOrder] => 0
                                    [RevenueCategoryID] => 7
                                    [IATAStandardCodeType] => 
                                    [ServiceActive] => 1
                                    [MaxCountFlightLevel] => 0
                                    [QuantityAvailable] => 8
                                    [StartSalesDays] => -1
                                    [ApplicableTaxes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BoardingPassSsrOrder] => 999
                                    [Name] => Blind Passenger
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [LogicalFlightID] => 4569
                                    [ServiceID] => 0
                                    [DepartureDate] => 2017-04-03T00:00:00
                                    [OperatingCarrier] => 
                                    [MarketingCarrier] => 
                                    [CodeType] => EMSA
                                    [Description] => 
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [Amount] => 0.0
                                    [AmountActive] => 1
                                    [AmountType] => Flat Fee
                                    [CategoryID] => 221
                                    [SSRCode] => EMSA
                                    [Display] => 1
                                    [MaxCountServiceLevel] => 1
                                    [Refundable] => 1
                                    [PNLActive] => 1
                                    [CutoffHours] => 0
                                    [Commissionable] => 
                                    [DisplayOrder] => 0
                                    [RevenueCategoryID] => 7
                                    [IATAStandardCodeType] => 
                                    [ServiceActive] => 1
                                    [MaxCountFlightLevel] => 1
                                    [QuantityAvailable] => 1
                                    [StartSalesDays] => -1
                                    [ApplicableTaxes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BoardingPassSsrOrder] => 999
                                    [Name] => Emotional Support Animal
                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [LogicalFlightID] => 4569
                                    [ServiceID] => 0
                                    [DepartureDate] => 2017-04-03T00:00:00
                                    [OperatingCarrier] => 
                                    [MarketingCarrier] => 
                                    [CodeType] => PETH
                                    [Description] => PET IN HOLD
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [Amount] => 25
                                    [AmountActive] => 1
                                    [AmountType] => Flat Fee
                                    [CategoryID] => 221
                                    [SSRCode] => PETH
                                    [Display] => 1
                                    [MaxCountServiceLevel] => 1
                                    [Refundable] => 1
                                    [PNLActive] => 
                                    [CutoffHours] => 0
                                    [Commissionable] => 
                                    [DisplayOrder] => 0
                                    [RevenueCategoryID] => 7
                                    [IATAStandardCodeType] => 
                                    [ServiceActive] => 1
                                    [MaxCountFlightLevel] => 0
                                    [QuantityAvailable] => 0
                                    [StartSalesDays] => -1
                                    [ApplicableTaxes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BoardingPassSsrOrder] => 999
                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [LogicalFlightID] => 4569
                                    [ServiceID] => 0
                                    [DepartureDate] => 2017-04-03T00:00:00
                                    [OperatingCarrier] => 
                                    [MarketingCarrier] => 
                                    [CodeType] => SVAN
                                    [Description] => SERVICE ANIMAL
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [Amount] => 0.0
                                    [AmountActive] => 1
                                    [AmountType] => Flat Fee
                                    [CategoryID] => 221
                                    [SSRCode] => SVAN
                                    [Display] => 1
                                    [MaxCountServiceLevel] => 1
                                    [Refundable] => 1
                                    [PNLActive] => 1
                                    [CutoffHours] => 0
                                    [Commissionable] => 
                                    [DisplayOrder] => 0
                                    [RevenueCategoryID] => 7
                                    [IATAStandardCodeType] => 
                                    [ServiceActive] => 1
                                    [MaxCountFlightLevel] => 0
                                    [QuantityAvailable] => 0
                                    [StartSalesDays] => -1
                                    [ApplicableTaxes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BoardingPassSsrOrder] => 999
                                )

                            [4] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [LogicalFlightID] => 4569
                                    [ServiceID] => 0
                                    [DepartureDate] => 2017-04-03T00:00:00
                                    [OperatingCarrier] => 
                                    [MarketingCarrier] => 
                                    [CodeType] => WCHR
                                    [Description] => 
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [Amount] => 0.0
                                    [AmountActive] => 1
                                    [AmountType] => 
                                    [CategoryID] => 1
                                    [SSRCode] => WCHR
                                    [Display] => 1
                                    [MaxCountServiceLevel] => 8
                                    [Refundable] => 
                                    [PNLActive] => 1
                                    [CutoffHours] => -1
                                    [Commissionable] => 
                                    [DisplayOrder] => 0
                                    [RevenueCategoryID] => 7
                                    [IATAStandardCodeType] => 
                                    [ServiceActive] => 1
                                    [MaxCountFlightLevel] => 0
                                    [QuantityAvailable] => 8
                                    [StartSalesDays] => -1
                                    [ApplicableTaxes] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [BoardingPassSsrOrder] => 999
                                    [Name] => Wheelchair (can Climb Stairs And Walk To Chair)
                                )

                        )

                )
```

This function is the ONLY one in the code modifying these values. If I set the function to always set them to false, all of them will be false. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what is going on, but I ended up just adding this bit to the top of the for() inside the function and then set the Services equal to the ServicesTest and it fixed it.

```
foreach($flight->Services as $serv) {
    $code = $serv->SSRCode;
    $flight->Adults[$i]->ServicesTest->$code = ($get['service-'.$code.'-'.$i] == 'yes' ? true : false);
}

...

$flight->Adults[$i]->Services = $flight->Adults[$i]->ServicesTest;
```